# Annotation of speech signal with Praat: criteria for setting vowel onset-offset?

Tags: phonetics, praat

I have a question for all those with experience in annotating acoustic (speech) data using Praat or similar software. Specifically, I'm referring to the annotation of vowels and the criteria used to determine vowel onset and offset based on both the spectrum and spectrogram.

1   What criteria do you use?
2   What are the pros and cons in your opinion?
3   Do you think it's important to consider waveform portions that do not show a strong formant imprint on the spectrogram (very low intensity, barely visible formants)?

Thank you in advance.